# How to set default value for assocc array function argument in PHP?

Tags: php

How to correctly write default value for assocc array function argument?

```
function foo($arr['key']='value');
```

Comment: '$arr = array('string' => 'string value');'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

function foo($arr = null)
{
    if (is_null($arr))
    {
        $arr = array(
            'key'   =>  'value'
        );
    }

    ...
```

You cant use the direct way you tried above. Just work with this little workaround

Else you might go with this:

```
function foo($a = array('key' => 'value'))
{
    ...
```

But in my opinion its a bit unhandy to declare an array in the function head. Its purely on you how you want to use it